# ngNonBindable in Angular - when directive will be deactivated?

Tags: angular

I've been reading https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#deactivating-angular-processing-with-ngnonbindable and found this section a bit confusing. Firstly, it states that:

> ngNonBindable deactivates interpolation, directives and binding in templates

but then, a few lines later, one can see words such as:

> ngNonBindable still allows directives to work on the element where you apply ngNonBindable

I understand that interpolation will be stopped for both element and its children, binding will be stopped for an element's children, but what about directives? In what scenarios applied directives will be stopped and for what elements - only children or elements and children?

I've read the whole passage about ngNonBindable and couldn't find this information. I think it's somehow confounding that it states that directives will be deactivated and then states otherwise without giving any example for such scenarios.